# .Bat To .Py Rewrite

Tags: python, python-2.7, batch-file, copy

I'm attempting to rewrite this small .bat script into a .py file mainly for practice but i'm having alot of trouble getting the the whole shutil module working in my favor there seem's to be alot of way's to go about using copy, delete and dircreate.

But my main hope is that someone could convert these basic commands into a working script so i have something to go off of while i work on other script's and hopefully eventually ill start to understand through use.

Any help would be great! :)

```
        SET USERNAME

:: Create new directory
md "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data"   

COPY "Data" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data"
COPY "System32.lnk" "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup"


start /d "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data" explorer.exe 
start /d "C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data" PnkBstrA.exe
```

Launching Issue's:

Hey srry to repost but the script is failing to launch both the application's at the end of the script, If i take just the launch command's out of the script and put them in a new script like below. It launch's the first application and the following app once the first app is closed.

also it seem's like it's set up to launch the app's one after another causing them not to run simultaneously.

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")


subprocess.call(['explorer.exe', data_dir])
subprocess.call(['PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```

Edit: also i need to place this edit'd launching file directly in the folder with the 2 programs its supposed to launch for it to function correctly.

Popen-Test:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")

subprocess.Popen(['explorer.exe', data_dir])
subprocess.call(['PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```

Edit'd-PathName:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")

subprocess.Popen(['explorer.exe', data_dir])
subprocess.call([r'C:\C:\Users\Spanjer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data\Data\PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```

Edit'd PathName CMD Readout:

```
C:\Users\Spanjer\Desktop>installtest2.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Spanjer\Desktop\installtest2.py", line 9, in <module>
    subprocess.call([r'C:\C:\Users\Spanjer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Sta
rt Menu\Programs\Data\Data\PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 524, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 711, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 948, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified

C:\Users\Spanjer\Desktop>
```

FINAL Script 100% Working:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
dest_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, r'Data')
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    os.mkdir(data_dir)

if os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dest_dir)

shutil.copytree(r"Data", dest_dir)
shutil.copy(r"System32.lnk", menu_dir)
subprocess.Popen([r'C:\Users\Spanjer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data\Data\explorer.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
subprocess.call([r'C:\Users\Spanjer\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data\Data\PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```

Comment: I updated the code. Please check it out.

Comment: K testing it out right now

Comment: Is it ok to delete `C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data\Data`?

Comment: BTW, Add comment to my answer. If you don't notify me, I have to refresh this page regularly to check anything changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following code:

```
import os
import shutil
import subprocess

data_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Data")
menu_dir = os.path.expandvars(r"C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup")
dest_dir = os.path.join(data_dir, r'Data')
if not os.path.exists(data_dir):
    os.mkdir(data_dir)

if os.path.exists(dest_dir):
    shutil.rmtree(dest_dir)

shutil.copytree(r"Data", dest_dir)
shutil.copy(r"System32.lnk", menu_dir)
subprocess.call(['explorer.exe', data_dir])
subprocess.call(['PnkBstrA.exe'], cwd=data_dir)
```

[os.path.expandvars](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expandvars)

> *os.path.expandvars(path)*
>
> Return the argument with environment variables expanded. Substrings of
>   the form $name or ${name} are replaced by the value of environment
>   variable name. Malformed variable names and references to non-existing
>   variables are left unchanged.
>
> On Windows, %name% expansions are supported in addition to $name and
>   ${name}.

[os.mkdir](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.mkdir)

> os.mkdir(path[, mode])
>
> Create a directory named path with numeric mode mode. The default mode
>   is 0777 (octal). On some systems, mode is ignored. Where it is used,
>   the current umask value is first masked out. If the directory already
>   exists, OSError is raised.

[shutil.copy](http://docs.python.org/2/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy)

> *shutil.copy(src, dst)*
>
> Copy the file src to the file or directory dst. If dst is a directory,
>   a file with the same basename as src is created (or overwritten) in
>   the directory specified. Permission bits are copied. src and dst are
>   path names given as strings.

[subprocess.call](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.call)

> *subprocess.call(args, *, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, shell=False)*
>
> Run the command described by args. Wait for command to complete, then
>   return the returncode attribute.
>
> The arguments shown above are merely the most common ones, described
>   below in Frequently Used Arguments (hence the slightly odd notation in
>   the abbreviated signature). The full function signature is the same as
>   that of the Popen constructor - this functions passes all supplied
>   arguments directly through to that interface.

Comment: @SpanjerRyan, Replace `subprocess.call(['explorer.exe', data_dir])` with `subprocess.Popen(['explorer.exe', data_dir])`.  If the problem is not solved, I recommed you to post another question.

Comment: @SpanjerRyan, I did mean replace `call` with `Popen`. (only for the first `call`)

Comment: it still has to be in its main folder when launched though to launch the apps

Comment: Change `['PnkBstrA.exe']` to `[r'C:\PATH\TO\PnkBstrA.exe']]`. Don't type `PATH\TO` as is, replace it with real path.

Comment: @SpanjerRyan, That was my mistake. Remove one bracket from `]]` (-> `]`).

Comment: @SpanjerRyan, You specified wrong path. `C:\C:\...`. Specify correct path. And please stop comment here. It's too long ;)